# How to find out what happened with a contract transaction

Tags: transactions, ether, contract-invocation

I have a question regarding one transaction which happened at the 17th of January 2018: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xabe5ac6176e1096bf4fbfa983cb8b04262ae1d57daf94ebb1668b5d45e3145f4 It should be transferred to my Blockchain Wallet 0x64f81834474FadF5A0AEd6C1e70C9B3b8300A1D3 but I cannot see it there. I remember that I used MetaMask for some ICOs back then but cannot really find out what happened with the 2.57 ETH. How to find out what happened with the money? Can you please help me to solve that riddle? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can see [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x64f81834474fadf5a0aed6c1e70c9b3b8300a1d3#internaltx), or by pasting your wallet address in Etherscan and clicking the *Internal Txns* tab.

Comment: But all point to a wallet address (0x64...) that belongs to me but doesn't list the 2.57 ETH

Comment: The link above is of transactions made **to** your wallet.

Comment: You can see [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x64f81834474fadf5a0aed6c1e70c9b3b8300a1d3) transactions made **from** your wallet, which can explain why there is no longer 2.57 ETH in it.